# Tabulator autoColumn : True => make all cell editable (~csv live edition)

Tags: flask, tabulator

Jinnja template

```
<div id="example-table"></div>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
//Build Tabulator 

var tabledata = {{data|safe}};
var table = new Tabulator("#table2", {
            data:tabledata,
            autoColumns:true,
            });
```

How can I make all the cells editable since {{data}} may change (generic html view in flask) ?

Note I only need input type editor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make all the columns visible then you can use the `autoColumnsDefinitions` callback to add an editor option to each of the generated columns:

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    data:tabledata,
    autoColumns:true,
    autoColumnsDefinitions:function(definitions){
        //definitions - array of column definition objects

        definitions.forEach((column) => {
            column.editor = "input"; // add input editor to every column
        });

        return definitions;
    },
});
```

Full details can be found in the [Auto Columns Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/columns#autocolumns)

Comment: thanks !! just diving into js but it's now clear. Awesome support as far as I can see through your many answers.